# Which GLSL version should i learn first

Tags: glsl, webgl

Hey i've started learning WebGl and soon discovered that the language was a tad too difficult to understand. So i've looked for a GLSL tutorial to first grasp the basics of this language before passing on to WebGL . I found this course online that explains GLSL 1.10 which is not by far the latest version(which i think is GLSL 4). So i wanted to ask if there is any difference between tthis version and the latest and will it matter which one i learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will only give you here a personal opinion, based on a personal experience.

You can ( note that I wasn't far from saying "should" ) start by GLSL 1.10, because since then a lot have changed : the developper has to manage on its own things that he hadn't to do before, in terms of transformations for example.

Those things are really important to understand, but if you want to start slowly you may want to avoid them at first. It's a bit like the end of the matrix stack in your OpenGL codes, you have to face it one day, but maybe not the day you begin using OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer ,can i ask you another thing, should i know OpenGL before i start learning WebGL ?

Comment: Well, i don't think so. In my mind, OpenGL and WebGL are the same thing on different supports : only interface specifications for 3D related programming. If you only want to do it on a browser, then I see no reason to go through OpenGL if that's not what you want.

Comment: ok thanks, webgl it is then since i have no interest yet of programming outside the browser

Comment: WebGL is based on **OpenGL ES 2.0** and thus is **not** "OpenGL on different supports". WebGL uses **GLSL ES 1.0**. Imho one should have an understanding of the WebGL/OpenGL ES 2 API first, before looking into shaders as they only make up a small part of the whole.

Comment: It seams that "the same thing" wasn't clear at all, by saying this, I wanted to say that they were providing the same kind of tools specification but on different type of support

Comment: So you mean they're graphics APIs, like DirectX, Mantle or Metal?

Answer (score 2):

GLSL is the Shading language, not the API used for the rendering itself (which is equivalent to OpenGLES2.0 in the case of WebGL). If the goal is to work on WebGL, I would recommend going from OpenGLES2.0 (the WebGL specification itself is written as a delta document over OpenGLES2.0), then GLSL corresponding to WebGL. This would also help understanding the more advanced desktop OpenGL versions.

The WebGL (and the corresponding GLSL) specification is at,

https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0/